# Datepicker jquery ui-datepicker-trigger

Tags: css

I need to add two calendar jQuery objects to the html page. I have the below setting for date picker. Have an icon image for opening the calendar object. For absolute positioning the icon image  doing the below css ui-datepicker-trigger override.  If i  have two calendar objects how can i create two overrides for the class because the  name of the override class naming convention doesn't to have a id name .  Pasted the code in http://jsfiddle.net/y6DDh/

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    position:absolute;
    left:330px;
    top:300px;
}
```

> ```
> $("#datepicker").datepicker({
>    //showOn: both - datepicker will come clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
>    //showOn: button - datepicker will come only clicking the calendar icon
>    showOn: 'button',
>    //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
>    buttonImage: 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
>    buttonImageOnly: true,
>    changeMonth: true,
>    changeYear: true,
>    showAnim: 'slideDown',
>    duration: 'fast',
>    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
> });
>
>
> $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
>    //showOn: both - datepicker will come clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
>    //showOn: button - datepicker will come only clicking the calendar icon
>    showOn: 'button',
>    //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
>    buttonImage: 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
>    buttonImageOnly: true,
>    changeMonth: true,
>    changeYear: true,
>    showAnim: 'slideDown',
>    duration: 'fast',
>    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
> });
> ```

Comment: Edited my earlier post. Yes since the I have two icon images  need to be placed at different positions how can i override the class ui-datepicker-trigger.

Comment: Thanks.  Had pasted the code  in http://jsfiddle.net/y6DDh/

Comment: Only one icon image of the #datepicker2 i was able to override with ui-datepicker-trigger. I want to override for #datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

```
#datepicker + .ui-datepicker-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    left:330px;
    top:300px;
}
```

For the second:

```
#datepicker2 + .ui-datepicker-trigger {
    position:absolute;
    left:530px;
    top:300px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y6DDh/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  In which file jquery generates this default class ui-datepicker-trigger.  I was searching for the this class and i was not able to find it.

Comment: `.ui-datepicker-trigger` doesn't exist in the CSS of jQuery UI. The image and its associated attributes are inserted by the `.datepicker()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and quick response.